# Symfony query on intermediate table

Tags: sql, symfony

I have a ManyToMany relation between `guest` and `event`. The intermediate table is `events`.

This sql query is working in PHP My Admin :

```
SELECT *
FROM guest AS G
LEFT JOIN guest_event AS E ON event_id = G.id
```

I'm trying to do the same query with the querybuilder, and tried this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('g')
   ->leftJoin('g.events', 'e', 'WITH', 'e.id = :id')
   ->addSelect('e');
```

but I get no results! Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try this:

```
$id = 1; // Your event id

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('g')
    ->select('e')
    ->leftJoin('g.events', 'e', 'WITH', 'e.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery();

$events = $query->getResult();
```

Read the docs about [Using Doctrine's Query Builder in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#using-doctrine-s-query-builder)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have entity reference
Probably something like this would do it:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('e')
   ->from('MyBundle:Guest', 'g')
   ->leftJoin('g.events', 'e', 'WITH', 'e.id = :id');
```

Comment: Thanks! but i get this Error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object.    This is the relation in my Guest Entity * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Prof\ProtoBundle\Entity\Event", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message=" ")
     */
    private $events;

Comment: @Albee You must create query builder from repository like `$repository->createQueryBuilder('g')`, not from `$this`. Check my answer update